# Sending a file over Websocket with Starscream on Swift 4

Tags: swift, websocket, starscream

I am wondering what the best option for sending a file would be.

I have to upload a cvs file to a server to be processed and then wait for the results of the process.

So far I convert the file to binary data like this:

```
let data = try Data(contentsOf: <URL>, options: .mappedIfSafe)
socket.write(data: data)
```

And it sends something, but I'm unsure how to handle that on the server side (Nodejs with websocket)

Is there another way to do this? I know using simple http methods I can send a file as it is, but I can't find a way with StarsCream.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How you solved your problem?

Comment: I never solved it actually. I used SocketIO, which is a higher level library that makes some things easier. The most important thing is there is so much more reading and support for socketIO.